# Usage of "what" in questions

Tags: questions, what, which-what

My teacher asked me,

> What friends were you hanging out with?

I think maybe she was wrong or maybe I do not know the other uses of "what" in asking questions.

Comment: Why do you think she was wrong? What is the wrong part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

"What friends" tends to indicate no clue.  "Which friends" tends to indicate that the questioner knows some of or all your friends and wants to find out specifically the ones you were hanging out with.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are going on in your teacher's question.

> **First**: She is *implying that there are **two kinds of friends*** - good/helpful friends and bad/unhelpful friends.
>
> **Second**: She is asking **"What" friends (which group) have you been around** that would have influenced you to do something (presumably bad)?